# Dynamic SQL sum column total from date += 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to sum totals of a numeric variable on a += days from a specific start date. The transactions are always updating within the range. For example then, I have:

```
Date              Animal    VetCost
2018-01-01        Cat       5
2018-01-01        Dog       10
2018-01-02        Dog       10
2018-01-03        Dog       10
2018-01-03        Cat       1
```

What I'd like to see for my output table is:

```
Animal     Begin Date Range    End Date Range      Cost
Cat        2018-01-01          2018-01-02          5
Dog        2018-01-01          2018-01-02          20
Dog        2018-01-01          2018-01-03          30
Cat        2018-01-01          2018-01-03          6
```

The Begin Date Range and End Date Range don't have to appear as above, but I need some way to know what the date range was.... Below is code to create sample data.

```
create table #temp
(   Date date,
    Animal varchar(12),
    Cost int
)

insert into #temp (Date, Animal,Cost)
    values ('2018-01-01','Cat', 5)
            ,('2018-01-01','Dog', 10)
            ,('2018-01-02','Dog', 10)
            ,('2018-01-03','Dog', 10)
            ,('2018-01-03','Cat', 1)

select * from #temp
```

Comment: What happened to the first row for dog?

Comment: Obviously you only care about dates. So why do you use DATETIME for your `Date` column?

Comment: Date is fine. Was just reusing code.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I wonder if you just want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(cost) over (partition by animal order by date) as total_cost
from #temp t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark Gordon's answer as accepted, but tweak it as shown below:

```
select t.animal,x.earliest,t.date,
       sum(cost) 
       over (partition by t.animal order by date) as total_cost
from #temp t
join (select animal,min(date) as Earliest 
      from #temp group by animal) x on x.Animal=t.Animal
```

This should give you want you want

Comment: This would work, but I need to see the daily sum for each unique Animal every day. Like sum(total) 1/1-1/2, sum(total) 1/1-1/3, sum(total) 1/1-1/4, sum(total) 1/1-1/5 etc.

Comment: This is really close... but in the example above, no row value is populated for Cat earliest 2018-01-01 to Date 2018-01-02. This is because their is no value for Cat on 2018-01-02. However, I still need the row.

Comment: Why wouldn't cat and dog have a row for just Jan 1?